# Recognising Eyes and putting spectacles through android app

Tags: android, face-recognition

How can I build an app that will put a spectacle on the face that is being shown (similer with facebook messanger's feature)? If I can identify the location of the eye , after that how can I make my own spectacle sticker ?

Comment: Try to read out about `openCV` that will help you complete your task

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this very good face detection API by Google

https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial

And you can also find and example of the above API in the same documentation.

Here is another stack overflow thread on the same.
https://stackandroid.com/tutorial/android-face-detection-example/

I have taken below screenshot from the sample app of Google face detection API. It's pretty easy and straight forward

Hope that helps

[image: screenshot from the sample app]